# Activeresource prefix_option missing when doing models association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, activeresource

Can anyone point me to how to add the prefix_option when dealing with active resource association? I have done the following but with no success:

```
class League < ActiveResource::Base
   has_many: teams
   self.site = "http://api-yyy.com/"
end

 class Team < ActiveResource::Base
   belongs_to: league
   self.site = "http://api-yyy.com/league/:league_id/"
 end
```

## And in the Team controller, I have :

```
def index 
  @league = League.find(params[:league_id])
  @teams = @league.teams 
end
```

But I'm getting ruby :league_id prefix_option missing when I visit the index page. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think your active  resource simply should be

```html
class League < ActiveResource::Base
   has_many: teams
end

 class Team < ActiveResource::Base
   belongs_to: league
 end
```

You should use routes to show how you want to view self.site , you should take a look at this article hope this helps http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @ranjith:Well, how do you set-up the routes? I currently have shallow routes but I did NOT find a way to set-up the routes and includes self.site...Any suggestion?